# Geocoding - cURL approach

Tags: curl

I didn't get successfully response with cURL example:

```
curl -X GET https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=<APP-ID-HERE>&app_code=<APP-CODE-HERE>&searchtext=Tracy+CA

Error: >& was unexpected at this time.
```

I use credentials for JavaScript/REST.

Also I tried in Web Browser Address Bar:

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=<APP-ID-HERE>&app_code=<APP-CODE-HERE>&searchtext=Tracy+CA
```

And I got: `invalid credentials for APP-ID-HERE`

I would appreciate if someone can help me:)

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

> app_id=APP-ID-HERE &app_code= APP-CODE-HERE

should be inserted in double quotes like that:

> --data-urlencode "app_id=APP-ID-HERE" --data-urlencode "app_code=APP-CODE-HERE" --data-urlencode

I hope will help for newbies:)